# How to split a String of numbers and chars, only by chars

Tags: java, regex, string, split

i need to split a String into parts of number sequences and chars between them. Something like this:

```
input:    "123+34/123(23*12)/100"

output[]:["123","+","34","/","123","(","23","*","12",")","/","100"]
```

Is this somehow possible, or is it possible to split a String by multiple chars? Otherwise, is it possible to loop through a String in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.

```
String input = "123+34/123(23*12)/100";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+|[\\+\\-\\/\\*\\(\\)]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works fine, afais.
my Paterns are: +-*/()[]%^ would my String look like this: "\\d+|[\\+\\-\\*\\/\\(\\)\\[\\]\\%\\^]" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead assertion based regex for splitting the input string.

```
String input = "123+34/123(23*12)/100";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split("(?<=[/)+*])\\B(?=[/)+*])|\\b")));
```

**Output:**

```
[123, +, 34, /, 123, (, 23, *, 12, ), /, 100]
```